# Create rounded button with inset edge, gradient and inset text with Gimp

Tags: gimp, gradient

This is my first attempt at seriously using Gimp. I am more of a front end developer slash developer myself and I have only used Gimp or Photoshop for very basic stuff such as removing backgrounds, cropping. So this the first time I want to do more and as I am planning on ditching PS I am trying to work with Gimp.
Please see attached image

[image: op-menu-buttons].

It shows simple rounded buttons with nice inner shades and a beveled background as well as inlaid text. How in Gimp do I:

1. Create this <strike>shade</strike> gradient effect on the button?
2. Do the <strike>inlaid/embossed</strike> inset text effect?
3. Make the button background with the inset lines?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Update**

Checking http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1K3L7RdbKw for engraved text (engraved = embossed)

Comment: If you already have photoshop, why in the name of Zeus would you switch to gimp?

Comment: google your needs there are so many tutorials.

Comment: why do you call the button "embossed" and the text "engraved"? Same effect. Look for the terms "gradient," "stroke" (careful with this in google!), and "emboss."

Comment: @horatio Yeah embossed and engraved are the same effects you are right.

Comment: @Lollero I like to try new programs and might go 100% Open Source in the future

Comment: So you'd rather use open source program just because? Did you ever consider how there's like gazillion tutorials for photoshop out there and if you're stuck with something, you are so much more likely to get help for photoshop. Don't do it man.

Comment: many tutorials for photoshop are suitable for other programs, provided the ability to mimic the result is there. The steps might be different, but the technique is what matters. Many photoshop techniques are analogs to printing and illustration/airbrush techniques.

Comment: Joonas .. that's not true. I have been using gimp for over a year now and I have found the online help for gimp very exhaustive, almost nothing you can't get done with it. Its also lighter than photoshop and free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use gradient to get that kind of background. 
Go through this nice tutorial to understand how gradient works :
http://mygimptutorial.com/round-web-20-button-with-a-metal-ring

And then play around according to your needs. Let me know if you need help with anything specific.

Comment: I took a look at the tutorial. The first three steps seem to explain how to make a circle and a gradient, which is part of what I need. Thanks! How to make the inset - think that is the word for it - lines and inset text is not explained there as far as I can see. This is the first answer to this question in weeks and one that is about doing this in Gimp. Very much appreciated!

Comment: Download this plugin : http://registry.gimp.org/node/186 and copy it to the location : ..\share\gimp\2.0\scripts where you have gimp installed. Then follow this blogpost: http://www.freshpage.co.uk/inset-typography-inset-text-with-gimp step by step and see if you can achieve the results. Let me know if you get stuck.